# Is it good practice to create a separate service for resources?

Tags: angularjs

So, I have angular resources like this: `var resource = $resource('/Auction/api/items/:id', {id:'@id'});`

I need them in multiple controllers. Is it a good idea then to create a service with all the resources, and inject them into my controllers?

Comment: Yes.............. Thats what services are for, you dont have to duplicate the call,logic etc... and abstract out any mapping mechanism

Comment: I think no, because you loosing the sweet part of angular, logic sharing :)

Comment: I am always creating separate services for different resources, you can put there some extension methods for them and generally speaking - the more files you have, its better ;) (advice just for beginners of course..)

Comment: Not sure if it is good or not, we create a service for each resource, and then inject resources into our data services. That way we know which resources does the data service depend on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, since services are singletons in Angular.js, it's the perfect place to create a shared resource. However instead of creating **one** huge service, create individual services for your resources.